# Расчет свободного ip адреса

Tags: python

Нужно найти свободный ip адрес в сети к примеру 10.0.0.0/22. IP адреса занятые будут хранится в базе mysql, вопрос в каком формате лучше хранить чтобы удобно было рассчитать и какой алгоритм лучше применить. Есть один вариант но он долгий по расчету через xrange и сравнивать их с занятыми ip адресами.

Comment: А занятые у Вас в базе? Или динамически определять хотите?

Comment: Будут в базе находится, но еще точно не знаю в каком формате записывать в базу лучше.

Comment: Храните в числовом виде, выбирайте MAX и прибавляйте 1. Естественно, для параллельного доступа алгоритм надо модифицировать с учетом процедуры (Ваших правил) выдачи нового адреса.

Если нужно повторное использование, то можно завести еще одну таблицу - ранее использованных, а теперь свободных. Оттуда можно выдавать MIN и перемещать в таблицу используемых.

Ну, и дальше в том же духе.

А вообще, для разработки нормального алгоритма, в вопросе недостаточно сведений о задаче в целом.

Кстати /22 - это маска? Странная какая-то.

Comment: Есть класс сети А выдали /18 ripe.net для экономии адресов использую технологию от cisco ip unnumbered на каждый loopback вешаю по /22. У нас технология vlan на дом, приблизительно 30 vlan принадлежит к одному loopback с префиксом /22. Задача составить базу с vlan привязать их в loopback и выдавать IP адреса свободные клиентам. Используются технология option 82. Свободный адрес заводится в билинг UTM5. Вот небольшие сведения)

Comment: Я как-то занимался такими вычислениями. Начинал с ряда-на-адрес, закончил sparse-списками с парами-диапазонами. Как не крутился — неудобное занятие с непонятной выгодой.

Рекомендую — храните в БД и свободные. Я весь пул загнал в таблицу с foreign key к сессиям. Грубо: `CREATE TABLE client_ips (ip INET PRIMARY KEY, session_id INTEGER REFERENCES sessions_active.id)`. Выборка численности свободных/занятых тривиальный `COUNT(*) … WHERE session_id IS [NOT] NULL`, выборка одного любого свободного адреса — тривиальное `SELECT ip FROM client_ips WHERE session_id IS NULL LIMIT 1`.

Comment: В PostgreSQL есть специальный тип `INET`, которым я воспользовался, а в MySQL, думаю, если не городить sparse-списки, то проще всего, `VARCHAR(15)`/`VARCHAR(39)`.

Comment: в mysql тоже есть inet_aton() и обратное преобразование inet_ntoa(). Смысл понятен. Будем писать и переходить на public address.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю стоит копать в сторону работы с двоичной системой и бинарных операций.